Eigenvalue decomposition of submatrix
for two rank- 1 matrices $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{A}_{\mathrm{sub}}$ I am interested in the relation between the eigenvalue decompositions (EVD) of ...
\begin{align}
&\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{Q}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\boldsymbol{Q}^{H}\,;\quad &\boldsymbol{A} = \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^{H}\,;\quad &\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{C}^{D}\\
&\boldsymbol{A}_{\mathrm{sub}} = \boldsymbol{Q}_{\mathrm{sub}}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{\mathrm{sub}}\boldsymbol{Q}_{\mathrm{sub}}^{H}\,;\quad &\boldsymbol{A}_{\mathrm{sub}} = \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{sub}}\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{sub}}^{H}\,;\quad &"\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{sub}} = \mathbf{v}(1:end-1)" \in \mathbb{C}^{D-1}
\end{align}
Is there something known about the relation between the eigenvectors (i.e., $\boldsymbol{Q}_{\mathrm{sub}}$ and $ \boldsymbol{Q}$)?
Thank you

First of all, $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, since $Av = vv^H v = |v|^2 v$ (and $|v| \ne 0$). Also, any (nonzero) vector orthogonal to $v$ is an eigenvector, with eigenvalue zero. So, you may take $Q$ to be any unitary matrix with $v/|v|$ in the first column.
Similarly, $v_\text{sub}$ is an eigenvector of $A_\text{sub}$ (with eigenvalue $|v_\text{sub}|^2 < |v|^2$), and so are the (nonzero) vectors orthogonal to $v_\text{sub}$ (again with eigenvalue zero).

A follow-up question: If $\boldsymbol{Q} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mathbf{v}}{||\mathbf{v}||}&\mathbf{q}{2}&\dotsc \mathbf{q}{D}\end{bmatrix}$ is unitary, and $\boldsymbol{Q}{\mathrm{sub}} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mathbf{v}{\mathrm{sub}}}{||\mathbf{v}{\mathrm{sub}}||}&\mathbf{q}{\mathrm{sub},2}&\dotsc \mathbf{q}{\mathrm{sub},D-1}\end{bmatrix}$ is another unitary matrix. Is there also some relation between $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{q}{2}&\dotsc \mathbf{q}{D}\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{q}{\mathrm{sub},2}&\dotsc \mathbf{q}_{\mathrm{sub},D-1}\end{bmatrix}$?

I think if you start with $\mathbf{Q}\text{sub}$, you could add a row of zeros at the bottom and then replace the first column with $\mathbf{v}/|\mathbf{v}|$, and the columns would still be orthogonal. Then adding a column orthogonal to the rest would give you a working $\mathbf{Q}$ - so $\mathbf{q}{i}$ would be $\mathbf{q}_{\text{sub},i}$ with a zero added at the end.

I was wondering more in the direction of common spanned (sub)space or similar. Do you know whether, e.g. the span of the eigenvectors $\mathbf{q}{2}\dotsc \mathbf{q}{D}$ is somehow related to the span of the eigenvectors $\mathbf{q}{\mathrm{sub},2}\dotsc\mathbf{q}{\mathrm{sub},D-1}$
